# Cordova open native contact details page

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to retrieve and store a reference to a contact from the native addressbook with cordova and to open the native contact details page?

The contacts-plugin does not seem to provide any usefull method.

Answer (score 0):

1. add plugin "org.apache.cordova.contacts" from command prompt.
2. Use java Script :

```js
function onSuccess(contacts) {
  alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
};

function onError(contactError) {
  alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "Bob";
options.multiple = true;
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

and you can also store from success function.

For more information please goto http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.contacts

Comment: Is it possible to show the native contact details page for the provided id?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, other possible fields are: displayName, name, nickname, phoneNumbers, emails, addresses, ims, organizations, birthday, note, photos, categories, and urls.